# Trying to get a JSON response that includes square brackets from this MySQL PHP code (objects and arrays)

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

php code:

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","thinkorders"); //Database connection start
$sql = "select * from psv_post"; //fetch table data 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql); //process query
$json_response = array();  //main array 
$shipping_address_details = array(); 
$items_details = array();
while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    //main array
    $json_response['contact_id']  = $row['contact_id'];

    //shipping_address details array 
    $shipping_address_details['country'] = $row['shipping_address_country'];

    //items_details array
    $items_details['type'] = $row['items_type'];

    //push shipping address into shipping_address details array 
    $json_response['shipping_address'][] = $shipping_address_details;

    //push items into items_details array 
    $json_response['items'][] = $items_details;

}
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
//echo json_encode($json_response);
$json_output =  json_encode($json_response); //OUTPUT  
//remove square braces from json string 
$json_output = str_replace('[','',$json_output);
echo $json_output = str_replace(']','',$json_output);

?>
```

this code returns:

```
{
  "contact_id": "625",
  "shipping_address": {
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "items": {
    "type": "paper"
  }
}
```

i need it like this:

```
{
  "contact_id": "625",
  "shipping_address": {
    "country": "USA"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "paper"
    }
  ]
}
```

After searching for a couple of hours it seems that its an array inside an object (see the square brackets), but everything i try has not worked. If someone can see an easy fix, please reply. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of code

```
//remove square braces from json string 
$json_output = str_replace('[','',$json_output);
echo $json_output = str_replace(']','',$json_output);
```

Comment: Awesome, that made them appear for my "items" but now they also appear in my "shipping address". great suggestion though, ill post the progress when i solve it, i only need them in my "items".

Answer (score 0):

After I removed the code that kalloz recommended, all I had to do is remove the "[]" from my push string:

```
//push shipping address into shipping_address details array 
$json_response['shipping_address'] = $shipping_address_details;
```

and of course edit the new last line to add "echo":

```
echo $json_output =  json_encode($json_response); //OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question details, your answer, and your comment, I believe I understand your coding intent and I would like to offer a logical rewrite so that your process is a bit more direct and readable.

Untested Code: ([resultset to array demo](https://3v4l.org/R5D4Q))

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
if (!$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "thinkorders")) {
    $response = 'Connection Error'; // $mysqli->connect_error;
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT contact_id,
                   shipping_address_country,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(items_type)
            FROM psv_post
            WHERE contact_id = 625
            GROUP BY contact_id";
    if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        $response = 'Syntax Error'; // $mysqli->error
    } elseif (!$row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc()) {
        $response = 'Possible Logic Error - No Rows Found';
    } else {
        $response = [
            'contact_id' => $row['contact_id'],
            'shipping_address' => ['country' => $row['shipping_address_country']],
            'items' => array_map(function($v) {return ['type' => $v];}, explode(',', $row['items_type']))
        ];
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

1. If you have no control over the construction of your json string, never use string functions to modify (hack at) a json string.  Rather, you should decode it, modify the elements/objects/etc then re-encode when you are done.  Of course, if you DO have control of the construction, then try to correct the array before encoding.
2. A `header()` declaration is probably  not necessary, but if you want/need it then use `application/json`.
3. Build in some error reporting to make debugging simple.
4. Instead of iterating and overwriting column values that never change, use `GROUP_` calls in your query.  This will set up the resultset processing so that only a single column (which may have multiple values) will be iterated.
5. No matter what happens in your process, always echo a json string.

p.s. your snippet is written in a way that suggests you will only target one `contact_id`'s data.  If this is true, I wonder how that id is being determined.  If the targeting id is being passed in (via GET/POST or other untrustworthy means) then you should cast the value as an integer or use a prepared statement with a placeholder and a bound parameter for security reasons.

Comment: I have painstakingly written this answer from scratch on my phone (took quite a while), so if have any typos or mistakes please leave me a comment.

Comment: @Eddie what do you think?